# MKV Video files are not paying properly.

Tags: mkv

MKV Video files are not paying properly.  SM player  only plays the audio, not the video.  Please hep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using VLC? you problably forgot the install the extra multimedia plugins in installation but VLC has them all you can just pres controll+alt+t to open a terminal and sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: I am already having the restricted extras installed and VIC installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Ubuntu search for "Ubuntu restricted extra" in Software center and install it. along with this, I recommend using VLC which also available in software center. right click on video and play with VLC

Comment: I am already having the restricted extras installed and VIC installed.